# Pandas: Get the index of a known value and copy that row to another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, iteration

If in an existing dataframe I iterate through a column for a certain value. How can I get the index of that whole row so that I can use .loc afterwards to append it to another dataframe?

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

df_a = pd.DataFrame([['a','Y','name1','5Y'],['b','N','name2','10Y'],['c','N','name3','3Y'],['d','Y', 'name4','10Y']], columns=['c1','c2','c3','c4'])

df_b = pd.DataFrame(columns=['c1','c2','c3','c4'])
```

I want to iterate through columns c2 and c4 so that if c2=Y and c4=10Y that row gets copied to another dataframe.

What I have done now is:

```
i = 0

for col in df_a[['c2','c4']:
    if((df_a.c2 == 'Y') == True):
       row_idx = df_a[df_a.c3 == 10Y].index.tolist() 
  
       df_b.loc[i]=df_a.iloc[row_idx]
       i = i+1
```

I  get value errors in this case, and I am unsure how to iterate and copy across correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `boolean_indexing` to extract the required data, and then use `append`:

```
df_b = df_b.append(df_a.loc[df_a.c2.eq('Y') & df_a.c4.eq('10Y')])
```

OUTPUT:

```
  c1 c2     c3   c4
3  d  Y  name4  10Y
```

Comment: In this case where and how do I apply a boolean mask to the index? I have two two columns to check and the if statement throws a Value Error. All the ways I've found how to do boolean_indexing point me to creating a df from a dictionary - which is not my case as I only have a df imported to my code. Could you please explain it a bit further?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this :

```
df_b = df_b.append(df_a[(df_a.c2 =='Y') & (df_a.c4 =='10Y')])
```

The output is :

```
  c1 c2     c3   c4
3  d  Y  name4  10Y
```